# git prepush hook: get branches pushed to

Tags: git, push, githooks

How can I get a list of the branches that are being pushed to in the context of a pre push hook? I know how to get the current branch, but it can differ from the one/many branches being pushed to.

I've thought of parsing the command, but I'm worried I might forget about some cases. Like `git push`, `git push origin master` will both push to master etc.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
while read oldrev newrev refname 
do
     if [[ "$newrev" != "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]] ; then
          branch=${refname#refs/heads/} 
     fi
done
```

Comment: close, but not quite right: see the `refs/heads/master 67890 refs/heads/foreign 12345` example in the pre-push hook section of the git hooks documentation: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html

Comment: Looks like `$(echo ${refname#refs/heads/} | awk '{print $1;}')'` would make it work

Comment: @Guig: simpler: `while read refname localhash foreignref foreignhash; do ...` But you should also check that `refname` (which I would rename as `localref`) actually starts with `refs/heads/`, too, otherwise pushing tag `v1.2` will attempt to do something with *branch* `v1.2`, which probably does not exist.

Comment: I've modified the answer to filter out tags

Comment: That's still not right, and the main issue here is that you have structured this like a pre- or post-receive hook, which reads lines with *three* values. The input to a pre-push hook consists of lines with *four* values. The four values are, in order, the local ref name, the local hash ID, the remote (foreign) ref name, and the remote hash. Given the way sh `read` works, you will get the last two in `$refname`, with the local ref-name in `$oldrev` and the local hash-to-be-pushed in `$newrev`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible loop, although it's not clear to me what you want to do with the remote branch or tag name, and/or the local ref:

```bash
#! /bin/sh

NULLSHA=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 # 40 0's

say() {
    echo "$@" 1>&2
}

while read localref localhash foreignref foreignhash; do
    case $foreignref in
    refs/heads/*)
        reftype=branch
        shortref=${foreignref#refs/heads/};;
    refs/tags/*)
        reftype=tag
        shortref=${foreignref#refs/tags/};;
    *)  reftype=unknown-ref-type
        shortref=$foreignref;;
    esac
    say "pushing to $reftype $shortref"
    case $localhash,$foreignhash in
    $NULLSHA,*) say "(push with intent to delete)";;
    *,$NULLSHA) say "(push with intent to create)";;
    *) say "(push with intent to update from $foreignhash to $localhash)"
       # for branch updates only, let's see if it's a fast-forward
       if [ $reftype = branch ]; then
           if git merge-base --is-ancestor $foreignhash $localhash; then
               say "(this is a fast-forward)"
           else
               say "(this can only work if forced)"
           fi
       fi;;
    esac
done
```

(note: this is not well tested).